# Custom permission is not able to show in permission table

Tags: django

I try to create a view permission in my staff model. However, it does not exist in the default permission table. The default permissions such as "Add","Change","Delete" still exist in the table. Do I need migrate again? Can anyone give me a hint?

```
class Staff(AbstractBaseUser):

  yes_or_no = ((True, 'Yes'),(False, 'No'))
  male_or_female = ((True,'Male'),(False,'Female'))

  name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank = False, null = False)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=100,blank = False, null = False)
  gender = models.BooleanField(default = True, choices = male_or_female)
  birthday = models.DateField(default =None,blank = False, null = False)
  created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
  is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False,choices = yes_or_no) 
  store_id = models.ForeignKey(Store,default=1) 
  REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

  permissions = (
            ("view_Staff", "Can see available Staff"))

  perm_list = set()
  def get_user_type(self):
    return "Staff"

  def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    if perm in self.get_all_permissions():
      return True
    return False

  def get_all_permissions(self, obj=None):
        return self.perm_list

  def asgin_perm(self,perm,object=None):
    self.perm_list.add(perm)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: Yes - you need to migrate after adding permissions to the model.

Comment: I have already try it, but it does not work. Is it necessary to delete all migration files and database, then try it again?

Comment: So what's the migration output,  does it show any errors?

Comment: @ SvekarP No errors come out, but it is fail to add custom permission in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Should you set custom permissions in a meta class like this ...

```
class Meta:
    permissions = (
        ("view_staff", "Can see available staff"),
    )
```